# Can `pip_index_urls` be used with Vertex pipelines?

Tags: google-cloud-ml, kubeflow-pipelines, google-artifact-registry

In [kfp-1.8.12](https://pypi.org/project/kfp/) there is a pretty useful new feature whereby we can specify custom indices for python dependencies in the component decorator (see [this PR](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/pull/7453)).

I've got a component that uses a python package already hosted on GCP Artifact Registry under a pypi repository. At the moment to use that, I'm generating a separate Docker image including that package and using that as the base image for my component.

It'd be cleaner if I could just install the package directly from the internal pypi index, but the authentication doesn't appear to work. If I include my internal index as part of `pip_index_urls` the component prompts for a `User` and immediately fails:

`User for <region-redacted>-python.pkg.dev:`

Is there a way of authenticating vertex pipelines with a pypi repository hosted on Artifact Registry?

Comment: Maybe this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication) might help you

Comment: In this case I need whatever service that is coordinating Vertex AI Pipelines to be authenticated though, rather than my local environment. I'm not sure how I can use that documentation to ensure the Vertex running environment is authenticated?

Comment: I searched for some other way to achieve what you are trying to do, and found this [tutorial](https://lukwam.medium.com/python-packages-in-artifact-registry-d2f63643d2b7) in there it explains that it can be done using cloud functions

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the [instructions to run set up authentication](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication) for your Artifact Registry Python Index, however, you have to do that *before* KFP starts to try to install packages.

Because setting that up requires installing some packages, and if that requires authentication...

So the solution is to put the instructions to set up the authentication (it's just `pip install keyring keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth`) into a `Dockerfile` and generate a custom image. Don't install Docker, use [Cloud Build to build the image](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers). Then run your Kubeflow component on Vertex AI with that custom image.

Another solution of course, would be to add the installation to the packages that you want to the Cloud Build, so that your custom image has everything you need already. That has the added benefit that your KFP component starts up a bit faster, because it doesn't need to install anything.